# Should you use InfluxDBClient's close() method?

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python

[As mentioned in the API documentation](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html#influxdb.InfluxDBClient.close) of the InfluxDB Python, the InfluxDBClient has a method close(). Are you supposed to always use it or is it closed automatically?